# Why can you not divide both sides of the equation, when working with exponential functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

We recently started with exponential functions, and I did this task for fun, but I apparently did everything wrong. I just don't get why it is wrong. I am aware of some logarithmic properties like $\log(\frac{x}{y})= \log(x)-\log(y)$ and $\log(x\cdot y)=\log(x)+\log(y)$ (though i don't really understand why that works and if $x$ and $y$ have to be variables or parameters. And I also don't know when to use these properties.)

The task:

Find the intersection point of $g(x)=3\cdot0.4^x$ and $f(x)=0.5\cdot1.5^x$

This is how i did it (and the solution is wrong):

$0.5\cdot1.5^x=3\cdot0.4^x$

$(0.5\cdot1.5^x)\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1.5^x}=(3\cdot0.4^x)\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1.5^x}$

$\frac{1}{6}=\frac{0.4^x}{1.5^x}$

$\frac{1}{6}=(\frac{0.4}{1.5})^x$

$\frac{1}{6}=x\cdot \log(\frac{4}{15})$

$\frac{1}{6\cdot \log(\frac{4}{15})}=x$

$-0,290$, which is terribly wrong.

---

The correct solution/approach:

$0.5\cdot1.5^x=3\cdot 0.4^x$

$\log(0.5\cdot 1.5^x)=\log(3\cdot 0.4^x)$

$\log(0.5)+\log(1.5^x)=\log(3)+\log(0.4^x)$

$\log(0.5)+x\cdot \log(1.5)=\log(3)+x\cdot \log(0.4)$

$\log(0.5)-\log(3)=x\cdot \log(0.4)-x\cdot \log(1.5)$

$\log(0.5)-\log(3)=x\cdot (\log(0.4)-\log(1.5))$

$\frac{\log(0.5)-\log(3)}{\log(0.4)-\log(1.5)}=x=1,36$

I would appreciate if someone could tell me why I wasn't able to divide and basically do the first approach.

Comment: Is there an equals sign missing in the statement of the task? Should that be $g(x)=3\cdot0.4^x$ ?

Comment: $\log(x\cdot y)=\log(x)+\log(y)$ corresponds to  $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$ while $\log(\frac{x}{y})= \log(x)-\log(y)$ corresponds to  $a^b / a^c=a^{b-c}$

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue happens when you jump from
$$\frac{1}{6} = \left (\frac{4}{15} \right )^{x}$$
to
$$\frac{1}{6} = x\ln\left (\frac{4}{15} \right ).$$
In this step you have taken the logarithm of the right hand side and *only* the right hand side. What you need to do is take the logarithm of *both* sides
$$\ln \left (\frac{1}{6} \right ) = x\ln\left (\frac{4}{15} \right ).$$
and then divide to obtain
$$x = \frac{\ln(1/6)}{\ln(4/15)} \approx 1.36$$

Comment: oh.... so the approach was right, but it was only that little mistake that resulted in an error? So i do not have to actually make use of the logarithmic properties?

Comment: The logarithmic properties are the reverse version of the exponential properties.  You can generally use one or the other, but some may be easier than the other.  (If you look at the last line of the official solution, you can use log(.5)-log(3) = log(.5/3) = log(1/6) and log(.4)-log(1.5) = log(.4/1.5) = log(4/15) to see that your corrected solution matches the official solution.

Comment: That explanation makes so much sense and it's way more intuitive for me now. While I'm at it I would like to ask, why you used ln instead of the log. I am always confused, when to use which. I know log without any base is log to the base of 10 and ln is log to the base of e, but does the base matter when trying to manipulate an equation?

Comment: You should choose the appropriate log base depending on the problem at hand. If you have e^x thrown all around, you should use ln. If you have 10^x, then it's better to use log_10. If you have another common exponentiation base, use that base to logarithm. In this case, when bases are all different, it doesn't really matter and you can choose whatever is easier/more familiar to you.

Comment: notation is flexible. the rules work no matter what you call it. in some fields log is the natural log (or even log2). it doesn't really matter which you use as long as you are consistent.

Comment: I would add onto @OscarSmith's comment about "notation is flexible" -- this pertains _just_ to the `log` notation. `log_2`, `ln`, `log_{10}`, and so on are all consistent. So in many fields you will see people avoid the use of `log` by itself purely because it's ambiguous (you never know what your reader will assume it means).

But you should use whatever notation your course is using, to be consistent.